# Model does not update through javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC view from which I open a JQuery dialog. Then from this JQuery dialog I open another JQuery dialog.

I pass the data from view to the first dialog using ajax call. I display this data on the first dialog view. This view is read-only. I open another dialog from the first dialog and pass data using ajax call. The second view modifies the data.

When I submit the second form/dialog, I call a javascript method updateData

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveData", "GenericData", new AjaxOptions{
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
HttpMethod = "POST",
OnSuccess = "updateData"}, new { @id = "Adddt", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

In this javascript method, I get the modified data sent from the second dialog. So I modify the HTML elements of the first dialog as:

```
function updateData(data)
{
    //set the grid values
    document.getElementById('tdnewdate').innerHTML = data.Object.DateFound;                     
     //set the model data
    document.getElementById('txtnewdate').value = data.Object.DateFound; 
}
```

The first dialog view contains code like this:

```
<td id="tdnewdate” >
@Model.DateFound
</td>
<td>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => @Model.DateFound, new { id = "txtnewdate", style = "display:none" })
</td>
```

The first statement modifies the form HTML element to display modified values.
However the second statement should modify the Model.

Now when I submit the first dialog, I can see that the Model has been modified.
However, when I try to edit the first dialog again, I get the original model values, instead of modified ones.

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'edit the first dialog again'? You amend the value of your textbox with JavaScript and then do what?

Comment: The first dialog view is a grid with Edit command with each row. When I click Edit for any row, the details of that row appear in the second dialog where they can be edited. The TextBox on the first dialog are hidden fields, only used to pass changes to the Model.

Comment: Please post the view for the first dialog and the controller method for the Edit link.